# How to serialize sql query to json?

Tags: json, django, django-serializer

I'm trying to serialize sql query to json:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT b.tonode, n.name, b.fromnode FROM zusers u JOIN znode n
                                                    ON u.code = n.created_by
                                                JOIN zbond b
                                                    ON b.code = n.code
                                                WHERE u.userid = %s""", [user_id] )

data = serializers.serialize('json', rows, fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent'))
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to serialize not model's objects, but sql query?

Comment: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: check my edit, to find why error occur. you must convert your result to django models object and pass it to serializer.

Comment: did u figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT b.tonode, n.name, b.fromnode FROM zusers u JOIN znode n ON u.code = n.created_by JOIN zbond b ON b.code = n.code WHERE u.userid = %s""", [user_id])
rows = cursor.fetchall()
result = []
keys = ('id','name','parent',)
for row in rows:
    result.append(dict(zip(keys,row)))
json_data = json.dumps(result)
return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 2):

base on [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-data):

> Actually, the second argument can be any iterator that yields Django model instances, but it’ll almost always be a QuerySet

try this:

```
query = """SELECT b.tonode, n.name, b.fromnode FROM zusers u JOIN znode n
                                                    ON u.code = n.created_by
                                                JOIN zbond b
                                                    ON b.code = n.code
                                                WHERE u.userid = %s"""%user_id

data = serializers.serialize('json', YourModel.objects.raw(query), fields=('id', 'name', 'parent'))
```

Comment: I don't what model I should use insead of "YourModel". I need just to serialize that list of rows

Comment: string formatting on SQL queries is not a good idea.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT b.tonode, n.name, b.fromnode FROM zusers u JOIN znode n ON u.code = n.created_by JOIN zbond b ON b.code = n.code WHERE u.userid = %s""", [user_id])
    cursor.fetchall()
    json_data = dictfetchall(cursor)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")

def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
     columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
     return [
         dict(zip(columns, row))
         for row in cursor.fetchall()
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT b.tonode, n.name, b.fromnode FROM zusers u JOIN znode n ON u.code = n.created_by JOIN zbond b ON b.code = n.code WHERE u.userid = %s""", [user_id])
rows = cursor.fetchall()
result = []
keys = ('id','name','parent',)
for row in rows:
    result.append(dict(zip(keys,row)))
json_data = json.dumps(result)
return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
def cont(request):
   try:
      get = cursor.execute('SELECT id, number FROM tblContract')
      qs = get.fetchall()
      data = []
      for obj in qs:
          item = {
                'id': obj.id,
                'number': obj.number 
                }
          data.append(item)
      return JsonResponse({'data': data})
   except:
      return JsonResponse({'data': 'errorrr'})  
   finally:
      con.close
```